# EXCEL: SUMIF In Array Formula Causing Errors

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have noticed that SUMIF does not play nice with array formulas.

To save on convoluted explanations of my motivation, here is a sample that demonstrates the issue:

```
=SUMIF(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10")),"<5")
```

My current work around would be:

```
=SUM(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))*IF(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))<5,1,0))
```

But my actual formula is quite lengthy and I don't want to repeat the criteria in both places.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Thank you

Comment: You do not need the IF: `=SUM(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))<5))` But I do not think there is a way around the duplication.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I'll use this form moving forward. I've learned that the SuperUser forum might be more appropriate for this question so I've opened it there too. I would really like to know the technical reasons why SUMIF won't accept this formula.